# Airflow scheduling task "t2failure" depends on task t1

Tags: airflow-scheduler

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    bash_command="Rscript Failure.R",
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_2',
    bash_command="Rscript Success.R",
    dag=dag)

t1fail = BashOperator(
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    task_id='task_1fail',
    bash_command="echo task1 failed",
    dag=dag)

t2fail = BashOperator(
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
    task_id='task_2fail',
    bash_command="echo task2 failed",
    dag=dag)

tSuccess = BashOperator(
    task_id='t_Success',
    bash_command="echo task1 failed",
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
tSuccess.set_upstream(t1, t2)
t2fail.set_upstream(t2)
t1fail.set_upstream(t1)
```

When task t1 fails to execute, ideal situation is t1fail is to be called.
But what I get is the task t2fail is also being called, as the trigger is set to one failed. Is there a way i can make the task t2fail to start only when the task t2 runs and it fails.

Comment: which airflow version are you using? This sounds like an unintended behavior. Airflow doc states ONE_FAILED should only be triggered by direct upstream task, since t1 is two levels above t2fail, t2fail shouldn't be triggered